# Making two classes reference eachother

Tags: python, oop

I'm trying to make a text adventure where different "place" classes can point to eachother.

For instance, I have a `Manager` class that has a reference to each place. Then I have a `Home` class, and a `Club` class, with references to eachother through manager. The problem is that I can't instantiate them due to the circular reference.

Here's how I solved it, but it's ugly, because I have to create the `places` member inside of a method instead of `__init__`.

```
class Manager:
  def __init__(self):
    self.home = Home(self)
    self.club = Club(self)

class Home:
  def __init__(self, manager):
    self.places = {}
    self.manager = manager

  def display_plot_and_get_option (self):
    print "where do you want to go?"
    return 'club' #get this from user

  def get_next_place(self, place_name):
    self.places = { #THIS IS THE BAD PART, which should be in __init__ but can't
      'home':self.manaer.home
      'club':self.manaer.club }
    return self.places[place_name]

class Club:
  #similar code to Home
  pass

manager = Manager()    
while (True):
  place_name = manager.current_place.display_plot_and_get_option()
  manager.current_place = manager.current_place.get_next_place(place_name)
```

In c++ I would set my dict up in the constructor, where it should be, and it would use the pointer of the `Manager`'s `home` or `club` members, since I only want 1 instance of each place. How can I do this in python?

**edit**: expanded code example

Comment: What are you trying to model here?  Why does Home have a reference to Club?  And what purpose does Manager serve?

Comment: When you play the game, there is a main loop that calls `display_plot_and_get_option` on the whichever the current place is. Then it passes the result to the `get_next_place` method above, which returns the next place to go to. Manager just holds the places, and other "global" variables, like player's name.

Comment: Is it mandatory to have a Manager class that holds references to instances of the other classes ?

Comment: Nope, but I don't see another way to only have 1 instance of each place going, and hold onto it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just have a dictionary that holds the references, and call the methods straight from the Manager (which shouldn't really be named Manager, as it does not serve that purpose now) instance.

```
class Home(object):
    pass

class Club(object):
    pass

PLACES = {
   'home': Home(),
   'club': Club()
}

class Manager(object):
    def display_plot_and_get_option(self):
        return raw_input('Where do you want to go?')
   def get_next_place(self, place_name):
        return PLACES[place_name]

m = Manager()
while 1:
    place_name = m.display_plot_and_get_option()
    m.get_next_place(place_name)
```

Comment: I think this is the best solution for python. And perhaps it's better to have to catch the callback and use it (in this case in PLACES), than reference the pointer. Maybe. Thanks

Comment: PLACES should probably go in the Manager class or be given to it through __init__

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `Home` and `Club` are just a couple of the many places you plan to include in your game, it would probably be advantageous to create a `Place` class. Specific classes can either inherit from `Place` or have a name as a data member. Then you can model connections with a tree or graph.

Comment: But how would this improve over what I have? I still need the manager since I need only 1 reference to each class instance. And I still need to build `places` in the method, which is what I'm trying to solve

Comment: `Home` and `Club` should not need to know about each other. Your `Manager` can have something like a hash table `{'home': ['club'], 'club': ['home']}` where you can retrieve a list of connections from each place without actually calling any methods in `Home` or `Club`.

Comment: I've toyed with this as well, but it just doesn't seem nearly as elegant as just being able to have the malleable pointers and reference those. But I agree that it seems like this is the best solution without pointers.

Comment: I agree, it seems like a graph of the possible connections between places seems to be the way to go. Or each Place class could have a list of places